High order finite difference schemes for boundary value problems on a finite interval
I have some questions. I'm going to assume everything is in 1d with a Laplacian operator. If I discretize the Laplacian operator using $p = 2a+1$ grid points with periodic boundary conditions, I obtain a banded circulant matrix that approximates the original operator to $O(N^{-p+1})$ accuracy and is diagonalized by a discrete Fourier transform. All good.
When I implement Neumann or Dirichlet boundary condition to high order, it is unclear what equation needs to be satisfied at the boundary. Using a three point stencil for the Laplacian, it's easy to obtain the solution using the method of so-called ``ghost points". However, as soon as you go to a higher order difference scheme, it is unclear which differential equation should be satisfied by the additional ghost points. Can ghost points be used in conjunction with higher order finite difference schemes, and if so, what equations do the additional ghost points satisfy to obtain uniqueness?
Furthermore, these matrices should be, in some representation, diagonalizable by discrete cosine and sine transformations respectively. The method of images seems to suggest that one simply solve the problem on an extended domain via the odd periodic extension of the original function for a suitably homogenized version of the Dirichlet problem and similarly via the even periodic extension for a homogeneous Neumann problem. Neglecting the cost of doubling the domain, this would allow one in principle to use a centered difference scheme at the boundary. However, it is unclear to me that simply using a higher order stencil on the boundary of a periodically extended domain implements a higher order scheme for the boundary.
Does a central difference scheme applied to a boundary node on a periodically extended domain enjoy the same level of accuracy as the central difference scheme applied on the interior?
What is the high-order finite difference approximation to the dirichlet and neumann conditions that are diagonalized by the discrete sine and cosine transformations?
